# Remove rows in 3D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need to remove some rows from a 3D numpy array. For exampe:

```
a = [[1,2,3]
     [4,5,6]
     [7,8,9]

     [9,8,7]
     [6,5,4]
     [3,2,1]]
```

and I want to remove the third row of both pages of the matrix in order to obtain something like:

```
 a = [[1,2,3]
     [4,5,6]

     [9,8,7]
     [6,5,4]]
```

I have tried with

```
   a = numpy.delete(a, 2, axis=0)
```

but I can't obtain what I need.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`axis` should `1`.

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = [[[1,2,3],
...       [4,5,6],
...       [7,8,9]],
...      [[9,8,7],
...       [6,5,4],
...       [3,2,1]]]
>>> numpy.delete(a, 2, axis=1)
array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6]],

       [[9, 8, 7],
        [6, 5, 4]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

A different approach would be to use slice notation, where you remove the last row of the 2nd axis.

```
>>> a[:, :-1, :]
array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6]],

       [[9, 8, 7],
        [6, 5, 4]]])
```